# Open an iframe in a new window with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page embedded with an iframe in a Wordpress post, and I want to add a link in the iframe that, when clicked, will open that iframe's html page in a new window. I want to be able to do this without knowing the URL of that iframe. Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open window using window.open. you can set height, width and other properties of child window. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjXHk/1/).

```
   <a href='javascript:void(0)'  onClick="window.open(location,'_blank','width=800, height=900'); return false;" >Html name </a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
       window.open(location,'_blank','width=800, height=900'); 
  return false; 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you just could pass the iframe's src value in an javascript window.open():

```
window.open($("iframe.test").attr("src"), "Window Title", "width=300,height=400,left=100,top=200");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href='pathofhtml' target=_blank >Html name </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery. You can use JavaScript to get the src of the iFrame using the ID.

```
 function popOut() {
        var src = document.getElementById('popOutiFrame').src;
        window.open(src);
    }
```

Next, call the Script with a button

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"    onclick="popOut()">
    <!--Optional: Font Awesome expand icon-->
    <i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>

<iframe id='popOutiFrame' src='http://example.com'></iframe>
```

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/mabarbeau/pen/jqjByw)